# How to remove characters from a string when flattening?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, regexp-replace

I have the following array as a record:

```
[
  "['Customer service', 'Ux/Ui']"
]
```

How can I remove `[]''` characters to get only the string `Customer service, Ux/Ui`?

I used lateral flatten as below, but still returns it with []

```
select regexp_replace(value::varchar, '[[]'']', '') as label_cleaned
from t1,
 lateral flatten(input => label)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's about the missing escape characters:

```
with MyData as (
select ['[''Customer service'', ''Ux/Ui'']'] as label )
select regexp_replace(value::varchar, '[\\[\\]'']', '') as label_cleaned
from MyData,
lateral flatten(input => label)
```

As you can see I added backslash symbols.